# How to count dynamically div display block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 div. 2 are hidden by default.
By clicking on a link "add" or a link "remove", I want the other div to be shown or hidden. And then, I would like to count dynamically div which are shown.

Here is my HTML :

```
<div id="clone1" class="billet">
    <input type="text" /><span id="test"></span>
</div>

<div id="clone2" class="billet" >
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div id="clone3" class="billet" >
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div id="ajout-suppr">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="ajoutBillet" >Ajouter un billet</a>
    <span>-------------</span>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="supprBillet" >Supprimer un billet</a>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".supprBillet").hide();
    $("#clone2").hide();
    $("#clone3").hide();


    $(".ajoutBillet").click(function (){
        var nb = $('.billet:not([style*="display: none"])').size();
        $('#test').html(nb);
        if(nb < 2) {
            $(".supprBillet").hide();
        }
        else {
            $(".supprBillet").show("slow");
        }

        if($("#clone2").hide()) {
            $("#clone2").show("slow");
        }

        if($("#clone3").hide() && $("#clone2").show()) {
            $("#clone3").show();
        }

        if($("#clone3").show() && $("#clone2").show()) {
            $(".ajoutBillet").hide("slow");
        }
    }); // fin du click function ajout billet


        $(".supprBillet").click(function (){
            var nb = $('.billet:not([style*="display: none"])').size();

            if(nb < 2) {
                $(".supprBillet").hide();
            }
            else {
                $(".supprBillet").show();
            }

            if($("#clone2").show() && $("#clone3").hide()) {
                $("#clone2").hide();
            }

    }); // fin du click function suppr billet


});
```

As you see nothing works.
Could you please show me an issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try something like this:    

jQuery('.ajoutBillet').on('click',function(){

        var lengthDivs = jQuery('.billet:visible').length;
        if(lengthDivs < 2 && jQuery('.supprBillet:visible').length > 0){
            jQuery('.supprBillet').hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afxh6bx8/1/). This does seem to do what is expected (by code). Are you referencing the jquery library?

I did make some changes to your count by checking on 1

```
if(nb < 1) {
    $(".supprBillet").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now shows and hides the inputs:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $(".billet input:nth-child(1)").hide();
    $(".billet input:nth-child(2)").hide();

    $("#new").click(function() {
        var count = 0;
        $(".billet input").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
              count++;
            }
        });
      
        $(".billet input:nth-child("+count+")").show();
        if ($("#total-divs").html() < 3) {
          $("#total-divs").html(count+1);
        }
    });
  
    $("#delete").click(function() {
        var count = -1;
        $(".billet input").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
              count++;
            }
        });
      
        if (count > 0) {
          $(".billet input:nth-child("+count+")").hide();
          $("#total-divs").html(count);
        }

    });
  
});
```

```css
input {
    margin: 4px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.actions {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="billet" >
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <a href="#" id="new">New</a> | <a href="#" id="delete">Delete</a>
</div>
Total: <span id="total-divs">1</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the visible div by jquery .is(':visible') function.
 Like this way :

Replace this

```
var nb = $('.billet:not([style*="display: none"])').size();
```

With

```
var nb = $('.billet').is(":visible").length;
```